# Replacing masked cloud areas with another satellite image?

Tags: landsat, mosaic, masking

I have various Landsat images of which many are cloudy. Using the cloud masking plugin available in QGIS, I was able to identify and remove the areas with cloud and cloud shadows from every image.

With this, I would like to replace the masked areas of one image with the data available from the others. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

mosaic images setting nodata = 0 (or other value) should work, as masked areas will be transparent, being filled with other underlying images.